# How to open Flutter app from background using FCM + data message?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I have implemented Google FCM in my app and successfuly recieving messages on all 4 message handlers(onMessage,onLaunch,onResume and onBackground).My main functionality is to navigate to a particular screen of the app.I implement this using NavigatorState key, which works great for 3 out of 4 handlers except for onBackground.When i send a data message to my app, onBackground is triggered and when it tries to navigate to specific screen i get this error:

> I/flutter (17050): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'push' was called on null.
>
> I/flutter (17050): Receiver: null
>
> I/flutter (17050): Tried calling: push(Instance of 'MaterialPageRoute')

What my main question is that is there any alternative way to navigate to the screen other than Navigator.of(context) or GlobalKey(NavigatorState) where the navigation state of app is preserved even after minimizing the app?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put some variable inside your notification payload to identify where you want your app to navigate to, and check for it like below inside your **onResume** and **onLaunch**

```
onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

String type = message['data']['type'];

        if(type != null){
          if(type == 'chat'){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> YourPageRoute()));

          }
     }
}




onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

String type = message['data']['type'];

        if(type != null){
          if(type == 'chat'){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> YourPageRoute()));
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, my main problem is with the "onBackgroundMessage" handler, if i try to navigate from this handler it gives the same error i qouted in my question("push called on null").Is there any way i can navigate from here? Example: Calling Screen implemented by VoIP apps.

Comment: the answer I posted above works for FCM both in the foreground and background, I haven't considered other cases but feel free for other answers for the rest of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late reply, but according to the Flutter docs, you can only do HTTP requests and I/O operations(e.g. read and write to databases). The reason being the onBackgroundMessage is an isolated function, it means you cannot call functions and variables inside classes.

I'm also stuck on this, just found out in the docs recently.

Note to self, read the docs first!

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/

Comment: I see, the only work around right now is to implement native code and implement a service in Android but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: One way to do it, as I am using right now, is to use REMOTE NOTIFICATIONS to signal my app for an update, then use that to trigger LOCAL NOTIFICATIONS. You can actually use navigator push for LOCAL NOTIFICATIONS. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications